# How to make use of Python Timestamp to be used as Matplotlib X-axis

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, timestamp, datetime-format

I am using SQlite in Python to store sensor data along with python timestamp `(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)`. I am writing another python code to retrieve data from the database and plot it with the Matplotlib library. I am retrieving the timestamp from the database as a tuple, and want to use it as the x value on the graph. I tried to convert the tuple to list and then to `datetime.datetime` object, but I could not get the complete timestamp. Sometimes I get only month and date but not hours and minutes and sometimes only the day and hours but not the month and year. I could not include the plot window. However sometimes it looked like `(MM-DD HH)` and sometimes `(DD HH:MM)` format. How do I plot the complete timestamp on to the matplotlib axis?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import serial,datetime
import sqlite3
from drawnow import *
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
from matplotlib.dates import num2date
conn = sqlite3.connect ('filename.db')
c=conn.cursor()
NodeID=2

make2 = c.execute('SELECT Timestamp FROM ClimateMaster2 WHERE NodeID=?',(NodeID,))
make2 = c.fetchall()
make2 = list(make2)
print type(make2)
# ''.join(make2)
print (length)
for i in range(0,length):
    make2[i]=datetime.datetime.strptime(make2[i][0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print (len(make2))
print type(make2)
print(make2)

y=np.arange(len(make2))
plt.plot(make2,y,'ro-')
plt.show()
```

The output looks like this in the console window

```
[(u'2017-02-07 17:08:51',), (u'2017-02-07 17:11:49',)...]
    <type 'list'>
    (u'2017-02-07 17:11:49',)
    <type 'tuple'>
    23
    <type 'list'>
    [datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 7, 17, 8, 51, tzinfo=<matplotlib.dates._UTC object at 0x0000000005983CF8>), datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 7, 17, 11, 49, tzinfo=<matplotlib.dates._UTC object at 0x0000000005983CF8>),...]

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Niki and welcome to the site. We generally try to keep questions to-the-point here, so I tried down your question.  Feel free to edit again if you aren't happy with it.   Also, are you able to show us exactly what the timestamp looks like when you pull it from the database?

Comment: @MackM Thank you for your feedback. I tried to edit it again and added the console output for the datatype and I could not add plot window screenshot.